# How to update all the columns values from all the tables using a php script?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update the columns values from an entire database. All the columns that contains a specific string (ex: id in the column clie_id) needs to have the value in uppercase. With other words all the id's must be in uppercase. I know how to do it for a single table, but is there a way to do it for all the tables?
Ok, it seems like everything is ok now. I have a problem with nested for loops. I need to do something like $s3=$s1+$s2 to obtain one single query, but I can't seem to get it right.
Code update. I have to print on the screen: UPDATE 'tablename' SET 'columnname' = UPPER(columnname) or if there are multiple columns in the same table UPDATE 'tablename' SET 'columnname' = UPPER(columnname), 'columnname1' = UPPER(columnname1) etc. Thanks!

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tabledb";

try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //get table names
    $sqlTables = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= 'tabledb'";             
    //get column names  
    $sqlColumns = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%UUID%'";
    // Prepare statement
    $stmtTables = $conn->prepare($sqlTables);
    $stmtColumns = $conn->prepare($sqlColumns);
    // execute the query
    $stmtTables->execute();
    $stmtColumns->execute();

    while ($rowTables = $stmtTables->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM) AND ($rowColumns=$stmtColumns->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM))) {
        $tables = $rowTables;
        $columns = $rowColumns;         
    }

    foreach($tables as $table){
        foreach ($table as $val) {
            $s1 = "UPDATE ".$val.", <br>";
            print_r($s1);
        }
    }   
        foreach($columns as $column) {
            foreach ($column as $val2) {
                $s2 = "SET ".$val2." = UPPER ($val2), <br> ";
                print_r($s2);
            }
        }

    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you need to get all tables with below query

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='your_database_name';
```

i.e

```
$tables = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='DBNAME'";
echo'<pre>';print_r($tables);
foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $columns = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='DBNAME' AND table_name='".$table->table_name."'";
        echo'<pre>';print_r($columns);die;
        foreach($columns as $column){
           //Be careful with this
           //$this->db->query("UPDATE ".$table->table_name." SET ".$column->COLUMN_NAME." = UPPER(".$column->COLUMN_NAME.")");
        }
}
```

Updated Code, Please replace your DBNAME,please be careful with array of array i used array of object here

Comment: Your Welcome,Accept the answer if it fulfills your need

Comment: One more thing. Can you check the edit? I need to have for each table the coresponding columns. Right now I have them separated( UPDATE tables and SET columns). I need to somehow concatenate,

Comment: share your whole code in edit like get all tables then get all columns then your foreach loops

Comment: I edited the question now. Thank you a lot for your help.